# Using awk to extract a string between different characters

Tags: bash, awk, macos

I'm attempting to write a bash function that gets the UUID of a VirtualBox VM. I'm pretty new to `awk` so I'm trying to focus on learning how to solve the problem using it.  I'm aware that I can use `sed` or even `cut` to solve this.

My "raw" output from the `VBoxManage list vms` is as follows:

```
$ VBoxManage list vms
"FreeBSD" {1aac7062-bd59-47ee-9261-2f6aa8d9ef53}
"Windows 10" {64942de7-beb9-418c-9f52-5befcb6f577b}
"High Sierra" {07f73e1a-a0c4-4190-ade1-79a2e432b4d6}
"Test Machine" {9d0953a7-ca2a-4667-8c5b-1a9f550b2956}
```

My desired output is to just get the UUID of a particular VM. Using "Test Machine" for this case, I'm looking for `9d0953a7-ca2a-4667-8c5b-1a9f550b2956` (without the brackets `{` and `}`).

After quite a bit of searching and testing, I've come up with

```
$ VBoxManage list vms | awk '/Test Machine/{ sub("{" ,""); sub("}", "");  print $3 }'

9d0953a7-ca2a-4667-8c5b-1a9f550b2956
```

It works, but I have to use to `sub` commands to extract it.

**My question is, is there a way to simplify the *substitution* portion of the action with an `or` type operator so I don't have to use two `sub` commands?**

For example, if I try `awk '/Test Machine/{ sub("{" || "}", ""); print $3'` it doesn't work - it prints the whole field including the brackets.

```
 {9d0953a7-ca2a-4667-8c5b-1a9f550b2956}
```

Is there a better way of extracting that string?

Comment: Allan, I've adjusted the tags to reflect Virtualbox being involved and bash *not* being involved in your question, since you're asking about awk code specifically regarding extracting a UUID from a virtualbox VM list.

Comment: @JeffSchaller - VirtualBox has **nothing** to do with this question other than providing the string I want to parse with awk in a script written and running in bash. You have this completely backwards.  Rolling back.

Comment: Others using VirtualBox may find this question useful.

Comment: @JeffSchaller... They may but it's not a VB question.  That said, I can (partially) see *that* argument for adding the tag but not *removing* the bash tag.  In the end, this is about parsing a string using awk in bash running on macOS.  The string just happens to come from VB.

Comment: The same awk command would work in any shell: zsh, csh, fish, etc.

Comment: But I'm not writing it in any any of those shells and macOS uses a very old version of Bash (v3.2) - awk for macOS is slightly different than GNU awk.  I wouldn't know the command was the same until I actually got a solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

-F field separator in awk. Here we are using 2 field separators. (either { or } )

```
VBoxManage list vms | awk -F"[{}]" '/Test Machine/{print $2}'
```

Comment: I went with this answer because it appears to be the most efficient and elegant *without* piping to another utility like `grep`, `sed` or others.  This works beautifully and I learned something (new) about field separators that wasn't in the "tutorials" I found on the internet.

Comment: It might fail if there is/are vms that has `{` or `}` on their name. I know It's highly unlikely but It could happen...

Answer (score 3):

Another way.

```
VBoxManage list vms | awk -F ' ' '{print substr($2, 2, length($2) - 2)}'
```

Separate fields by empty space

```
awk -F ' '
```

Print second column removing the first `{` and last `}` characters

```
'{print substr($2, 2, length($2) - 2)}'
```

Answer (score 2):

#### With Gnu grep (uses Perl-stye regex):

```
grep -Po "(?<={)[a-f0-9-]+(?=})"
```

... in other words, any sequence of hex digits and dash, occurring after an opening brace and immediately followed by a closing one.

#### With plain grep

```
grep -Eo "([a-f0-9-]+-){4}[a-f0-9-]+"
```

... ie, 5 groups of hex digits separated by dashes.

Answer (score 0):

```
  VBoxManage list vms|  awk -F "{" '/Test Machine/{gsub("}","",$NF);print $NF}'
```

output

```
9d0953a7-ca2a-4667-8c5b-1a9f550b2956
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ VBoxManage showvminfo 'Test Machine' --machinereadable | sed -n '/^UUID=/{ s///; s/"//gp; }'
1ce7ffef-8faa-4138-9b92-466698762f62
```

Instead of using the `list vms` sub-command, this uses the sub-command `showvminfo`, which gets all the information for a particular machine (here a VM called `Test Machine`).  With `--machinereadable`, this outputs the data in a form that is easily parseable.  The VMs UUID will be outputted like

```
UUID="1ce7ffef-8faa-4138-9b92-466698762f62"
```

which the `sed` command detects. It removes the `UUID=` bit and all double quotes and then prints whatever is left.

The `sed` command could be written in multiple different ways. A variation is for example,

```
sed -n 's/^UUID="\(.*\)"$/\1/p'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it using P.E. and bash syntax.

```
while read -r vmname uuid; do
  uuid=${uuid##*'{'}
  uuid=${uuid%'}'*}
  vmname=${vmname#*'"'}
  vmname=${vmname%'"'*}
  printf '%-15s %s\n' "$vmname" "$uuid"
done < <(VBoxManage list vms)
```

You can start the vms inside the loop with a match using a test or save the output in array and so on. It should also be safe even if the vm name has a `{` or `}` in it's name. I've been using that code in my script since 2013 :-)